# Understand Clojure's required: impact of a sequence of cascading required files

Tags: clojure

I tried to find the answer both online and in my books, and I have a hard time figuring out how this is exactly handled.

Let's take this scenario. I have a few files:

- `a.clj` - namespace: `aaa.a`
- `b.clj` - namespace: `bbb.b`
- `c.clj` - namespace: `ccc.c`
- `d.clj` - namespace: `ddd.d`

Each of these files does define a few functions. Then I have this sequence of required statements:

- `a.clj`: `[:require [bbb.b] [ccc.c] [ddd.d]`
- `b.clj`: `[:require [ccc.c]]`
- `d.clj`: `[:require [bbb.b]]`

Then my core application does `[:require [aaa.a]]`

My understanding is that when I compile my core application, the following happens:

1. Compile core file
2. Compile a.clj
3. Compile b.clj
4. Compile c.clj
5. Compile c.clj (is it skipped since it is already compiled?)
6. Compile d.clj
7. Compile b.clj (is it skipped since it is already compiled?)

My first question regarding this setup:

1. Are the files `#5` and `#7` recompiled or just skipped over by the compiler?

Then, let's say that I define a function `foo` in the file `c.clj`. If in `#5` the file is in fact re-compiled, would the function `foo` change its identifier? Somemething like:

- Was `#<ccc$foo ccc.c$foo@431a3bbd>` when first compiled
- Would be `#<ccc$foo ccc.c$foo@632a3cdt>` when compiled for the second time (if it is indeed compiled the second time)

I am asking these questions since what I think I am experiencing is that the files get re-compiled and the reference to my functions are changing depending on how files are required in the project.

But my intuition tell me that the already required files should be skipped if they are re-required down the road. However, it looks like that this is not what is happening, and so the reason for this question.

However, really tracking down this behavior is not a simple task, and it is why I am seeking for a deeper understanding on the impact of such cascading `require` statements before continuing my debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` takes an optional `:reload` or `:reload-all` key that respectively ask for the `ns` in question to be recompiled, or for a recursive recompilation of all namespaces from that file. If you do not specify `:reload` or `:reload-all`, the namespace will not be reloaded. This can be verified with a simple `println` at the top level of the namespace (outside of any definition). Changing identifiers should not be a problem, because your code should not be referring to identifiers, it should be referring to vars which resolve to an identifiers. Even if the value of a var changes (rebound), functions that capture the old Object that the var pointed to will still see the value (it cannot be collected by gc because they still hold a reference to it).

Comment: @noisemith great thanks for this answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. With this additional information I will continue my testing.